# Can I load XAML picture back?

Tags: c#, xaml

This is the startup image defined in XAML:

```
Source="/MyApp;component/media/person.png"
```

Then I replaced it in code:

```
personPhoto.Source = blaBlah(personID);
```

Now how can I load the default/startup image back?

Comment: Have you tried just setting the Source again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply store it in temp variable and assign it back when needed

```
var tmpSource = personPhoto.Source;
personPhoto.Source = blaBlah(personID);
...
//Set back to default value
personPhoto.Source = tmpSource;
```

Hope this helps